# Is it possible to use a Netgear EX6200 W-Fi extender for Ethernet connections?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, bridge

I have a main router and then in the other section of the house a router used as an extender (Let’s name this network “[Wifinetwork]”). I want to receive the Wi-Fi signal from the extender with my [Netgear EX6200](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/EX6200.aspx), then connect the Netgear EX6200 to my desktop PC with an Ethernet cable.

This would work by simply connecting the Netgear EX6200 as another repeater, but I do not want to create more unnecessary networks (which, going back to my previous example would be called something like “[Wifinetwork]_EXT”).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would configure the Netgear EX6200 as a Wi-Fi client in bridge mode. In doing so, your wired devices would be connected to the main router’s network via the Netgear EX6200’s connection, but the Netgear EX6200 would not be creating a new wireless network.

You should be able to go through the normal setup process for connecting the Netgear EX6200 to your main router, but after that is done, you will need to go back into **Advanced -> Wireless Settings** for the device and disable the access point radios. (Uncheck the boxes that say “Enable Wireless Access Point.”) You’ll want to be connected to the Netgear EX6200 with a wired connection when you access the admin pages for this.